# Ways to approach a Stop watch test in the form of unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, stopwatch

I'm very new to c# I've been tasked with creating a test that will tell me how long a search process takes. So I click a search button. Then I wait for the results to appear.

I'd like to try it in the form of a unit test with my triple A's The test ideally can take no longer than 3 seconds to complete it's search.

What would be the best way to approach this? and Would I need to do any setup before hand?

I just have the generic code so far.

```
    [TestMethod]
public void LocationNameSearch()
{
    //Arrange


    //Act


    //Assert


}}
```

UPDATE:
I'm having a go at trying to create a basic stop watch then I will build in the data i need from the dev code. Where am I going wrong with this assert?

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void LocationNameSearch()
    {
// Create new stopwatch.
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

// Begin timing.
stopwatch.Start();

// Do something.
for (int i = 0; i > 1000; i++)
{

}

// Stop timing.
stopwatch.Stop();

//Assert
Assert.AreEqual(stopwatch.Stop, 1);


}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to use the `StopWatch` class?  Or how to write a unit test?

Comment: A test is useful when you want to check the desired output of some process against the actual one. In this case it looks like you're trying to measure something just to gather info and so it does not look like a unit test responsibility.

Comment: Ok in a nutshell we require a test to see how long a search takes from A to B this can take no longer than 3 seconds. If it takes longer than 3 seconds then I need it to fire a warning. I've done unit tests before @Amy. It might be the case that the way I originally thought wasn't the best way if so what's the alternatives?

Comment: Alternatives to what?  It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: What is the best way to time a search in the form of a test c#, is my original post on the right lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not using the `Stopwatch` class but I prefer to use the [`[Timeout]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.timeoutattribute.aspx) attribute.

Usage:

```
[TestMethod]
[Timeout(3000)]
public void LocationNameSearch() { }
```

If the test takes longer than 3 seconds to complete, the test will fail.

Comment: Seems simple Im guessing I call the methods in the code if it takes longer than the 3 seconds as you say it fails. Which is exactly what is required.

Answer (score 0):

The assert should check the Elapsed property of the stopwatch and compare it to the maximum time the process is allowed to take.